# AxAcroPDF won't open hyperlinks

Tags: hyperlink, axacropdf

This is my very first post here, so I would like to start with Thank You. I found a lot of answers here.

I cant seem to open any link or hyperlink in pdf files with AxAcroPDF viewer? The Viewer is in a Windows Form and I use C#.

[example from AxAcroPDF Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRrVN.png)

Problem 1: When I click on a link nothing happens.
Problem 2: When I click on a local file link I get [this security warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfTaV.png) pops up and when accepted nothing happens?

But with Adobe Reader DC everything works just fine.

Thanks

Comment: Good first question! Unfortunately, it is so good no one seems to know the answer. However, I can say that I have encountered the same thing and have found a few others that have as well. I am inclined to suggest it may be a limitation of the control, by design. If I discover anything to the contrary, I will post back...